# Run parallel task and return the first completed task and run other in background to save results

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, redis, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a WebApi in .NET CORE 3.1 in which I'm trying to get results from a service (other third party). I have created multiple requests in my API for the same service but some parameters of every request are different, the results return from service will be different for every request but structure of result will be same.

As all requests are independent of each other I want to run all that in parallel. And I want to return the first result as soon as received from the service from my API, but I also want to run all other requests in background and save there results in REDIS.

I tried to create a sample code to check if possible:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Test")]
        public async Task<SearchResponse> Test(SearchRequest req)
        {
            List<Task<SearchResponse>> TaskList = new List<Task<SearchResponse>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                SearchRequest copyReq = Util.Copy(req); // my util function to copy the request
                copyReq.ChangedParameter = i; // This is an example, many param can changed
                TaskList.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething(copyReq)));
            }

            var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(TaskList);

          return  await finishedTask;
        }

        private async Task<SearchResponse> DoSomething(SearchRequest req)
        {
            // Here calling the third party service
             SearchResponse resp = await service.GetResultAsync(req);


           // Saving the result in REDIS
            RedisManager.Save("KEY",resp);

             return resp;            
        }
```

Now I'm wondering if this is correct way to dealing with this problem or not. If there is any better way please guide me to that.

**EDIT**

**Use Case scenario**

I have created a web app which will fetch results from my webapi and will display the results. 
The WebApp searches for list of products (can be anything) by sending a request to my api. Now my api creates different requests as the `source` (Let's say Site1 and Site2) for results can be different.

Now the third party handles all requests to different sources(Site1 and Site2) and convert there results into my result structure. I have just to provide the parameter from which site i want to get results and then call the service at my end.

Now I want to send the results to my WebApp as soon as any source(site1 or site2) gives me the result, and in background I want to save the result of other source in redis. So that I can fetch that too from my webapp on other request hit.

Comment: you have not describe your use case in a way which makes sense so it hard to say. you want to defer work, then defer it, by moving off the current thread. it you want a call back you then either need to request status or use two way communication tech like SignalR (out of scope). So again without a more concrete example of flow and why, it would be very hard to suggest anything. Your "problem" is not clear so its hard to guide

Comment: please give us more context so that we can get a clearer picture, without divulging sensitive information of course :)

Comment: I have updated the scenario. Please take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks pretty good; there's only one adjustment I'd recommend: don't use `Task.Run`. `Task.Run` causes a thread switch, which is totally unnecessary here.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public async Task<SearchResponse> Test(SearchRequest req)
{
  var TaskList = new List<Task<SearchResponse>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    SearchRequest copyReq = Util.Copy(req); // my util function to copy the request
    copyReq.ChangedParameter = i; // This is an example, many param can changed
    TaskList.Add(DoSomething(copyReq));
  }

  return await await Task.WhenAny(TaskList);
}

private async Task<SearchResponse> DoSomething(SearchRequest req)
{
  // Here calling the third party service
  SearchResponse resp = await service.GetResultAsync(req);

  // Saving the result in REDIS
  RedisManager.Save("KEY",resp);

  return resp;            
}
```

Note that this is using fire-and-forget. In the general sense, fire-and-forget is dangerous, since it means you don't care if the code fails or if it even completes. In this case, since the code is only updating a cache, fire-and-forget is acceptable.

Comment: Will there be any chance that my remaining task will not complete if assuming there will be no exception?

Comment: Yes. If the application exits for any reason, then fire-and-forget tasks will be terminated without warning.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. I will follow that. :)